# Безопасные заголовки

Tags: php, access-control

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers:  Content-Type, X-Requested-With");
```

Безопасны-ли эти заголовки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Абсолютно безопаcны, кода нет Ява-Скрипта

Comment: Делается аякс запрос к другому домену, тот не хочет выдавать ответ без этих заголовок.

Но проблему решил curl-ом. Без этих заголовок.